# Opening Child Form in External Application VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, external-application

I know it's possible to open an external application in an MDI form: [Opening external application inside VB.NET MDI Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783945/opening-external-application-inside-vb-net-mdi-form)

But what I'm looking for is to open a VB.NET MDI Form inside an external application, notepad.exe for example. What I want to happen is for the form to open inside the external program(notepad in this case)

Comment: What you're asking for makes no sense. You couldn't possibly open a FORM from your application in a program made to display text.

Comment: Notepad was just an example. What I am asking for is for an external program to be an MDI Container for a form in my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do what you are asking is if the program allows "Add-ins".  Some programs, like those in MS Office, will allow you to create add-ins to their programs which can be called in many different ways. I don't think I has see one that allows what you would call MDI Children but that does not mean there isn't something out there.

To get started creating add-ins for office, create a new project in visual studio using one of the supplied templates:

- New Project
- Templates
- Visual Basic
- Office

Or for visual studio:

- New Project
- Templates
- Other Project Types
- Extensibility

Comment: But I don't want it to be in ms office or vs. After a little research I have read that you could inject it. I'm quite clueless on how I would go about doing that though.

Comment: Never heard of it. Honestly, I would think that was illegal and would allow malicious activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596341/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-windows-form-application-into-another-application-as

That's kinda what I want. But I don't understand the content in the links provided.

EDIT: Also, what I am planning on doing is not illegal or malicious in anyway :p

Comment: I have an idea.

Is it possible to make a form that always stays on top of only a specific external window and I don't mean Me.Topmost but it has to stay on top of only a certain window and the form could resize when the external application is resized and maximize when the external app is maximized and so on.

That way I can make my form an MDI Container.